# Ubuntu 15.10 update breaks IBM Notes 9

Tags: gtk, 15.10, ibm-lotus-notes

I upgraded to 15.10 and now Notes won't start (probably because they changed the scrollbar).

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(notes:12215): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: How did you install it (was it via a package, tarball, etc)?

Comment: I installed it directly via deb package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember how I fixed this, but nowadays, just upgrade to 16.04 or higher and it will work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
```

To install the GTK Murrine engine.

Otherwise, is it because it apparently only supports fairly old versions of Linux (RHEL 5&6, Ubuntu 10.04 & 12.04) - see [here](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1351629539069&osPlatform=Linux)

Comment: I already had the murrine engine installed. I think the warnings aren't relevant and probably were there before the upgrade.
The interesting bit is probably:
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

The IBM link doesn't work for me, but you are right that notes only supports old versions. Still I got it to run on 15.04 and hope that it's fixable for 15.10.

Comment: The overlay-scrollbar package was removed with 15.10.

Comment: You probably need the i386 version: `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386`